# Android custom vector map mapview

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have to write a android app that contain a mapview.
I have my custom map vector and I want to show the current location on this map.
My problem is I don't know how to calibre the location to this vector image and show it in the MapView.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest would be to add a [MyLocationOverlay](http://code.google.com/intl/nl/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay.html) to the map. You'd also need to obtain the location from the Android LocationManager and center the MapView to this location.